# Java passing a generic type object as method argument

Tags: java, generics

I have the following java class, that has an instance variable property as a generic type passed when declaring the class.

When I try to assign the property passing it as a method argument, it does not seem to change its value if I change the value of the argument itself.

Code:

```
public class BST<T extends Comparable<T>, S>{
    private Node<T, S> bstRoot;

    public Node<T,S> getRoot() {
        return bstRoot;
    }
    public void setRoot(Node<T,S> root) {
        this.bstRoot = root;
    }   
    public boolean put(T key, S value){
        Node<T,S> node = new Node<T,S>(key, value);
        return put(node, bstRoot);
    }
    private boolean put(Node<T,S> node, Node<T,S> root){
        if(root == null){
            root = node;
        }
        else{
            if(root.compareTo(node) < 0){
                put(node, root.getRightChild());
            }
            else{
                put(node, root.getLeftChild());
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

When I do the following:

```
public class BSTTest {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        BST<Integer, String> bst = new BST<Integer, String>();
        bst.put(10, "Hello10");
    }
}
```

After doing the put, the bstRoot is still null, instead of being set to a value of Node object with key 10 and value Hello10. Is it not passing by reference then?

Comment: I don't see a `BST` constructor in the code you posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't look quite right:

```
if(root == null){
    root = node;
}
```

Why?  `root` is a variable defined in your method.  [It doesn't have the same lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40480/1079354) as a field in your instance.

```
private boolean put(Node<T,S> node, Node<T,S> root)
```

It would be more reliable to actually use `bstRoot` for an empty tree here.

```
if(bstRoot == null){
    bstRoot = node;
}
```

Comment: Although the other answer explains what the problem is, the link explains why.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is the following. In your first `put` method, you do this:

```
return put(node, bstRoot);
```

Your second `put` method looks like this:

```
private boolean put(Node<T,S> node, Node<T,S> root){
    if(root == null){
        root = node;
    }
```

So, in the first `put` method you pass `bstRoot` as the `root` argument for the second `put` method.

You seem to expect that `bstRoot` is passed by reference, so that the second `put` method will set `bstRoot`.

This is not the case. In Java, **everything** is **passed by value**. So, `root` in your second method is a copy of `bstRoot`, and modifying the value of `root` will not modify `bstRoot`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private boolean put(Node<T,S> node, Node<T,S> root){
        if(root == null){
            root = node;
        }
        else{
            if(root.compareTo(node) < 0){
                put(node, root.getRightChild());
            }
            else{
                put(node, root.getLeftChild());
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Here root has a local scope. You have to set this root to bstRoot. since bstRoot is instance variable.